# Refactoring editing user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Im working with a medium sized Rails application and I do this in every controller:

```
def create
  @object = Model.new(params[:model].merge(editing_user: current_user))
  ...
end

def update
  @object = Model.find(params[:id])
  @object.editing_user = current_user
  ...
end
```

Setting the editing user over and over again is not DRY. I thought about cleaning this up with an observer but it would need access to the current user. Observers do not have access to the current user, neither should they (Law of Demeter).

Any suggestions how to DRY this up between controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :init_request

  def init_request
    params[:editing_user] = current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure/) to dry up my controllers. It automatically finds or initializes a model instance, based on whether an :id was passed as a param, and it assigns the attributes from `params[:model]`.

To finish drying up your code, you could use the new strategy support (see the end of the readme) to automatically set the `editing_user` attribute on your model.

Comment: decent_exposure looks nice! I will definitely look into that, thanks for the tip. For this project I do not want any extra dependencies though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an `after_filter` for this. Perhaps something like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :set_editing_user

def set_editing_user
  @object.update_attribute(:editing_user, current_user) if @object && current_user
end
```

The difficulty, of course, is that you'll be saving the object twice per call. Generally though creations and updates don't happen so frequently that two database commits is a serious problem, but if you expect to be the next Twitter -- with massive database insertion load -- it could be an issue.

You could also possibly set this in a `before_filter`, but then you'd have to find or set the object in a previous `before_filter`. Otherwise `@object` will always be nil and the `before_filter` will never fire. You can use the filter ordering methods `prepend_before_filter` and `append_before_filter` to ensure the correct sequencing of these filters.